# Some sort of Virtual Spaces suddenly turned on in Notepad++, no longer normally responding to keystrokes

Tags: notepad++

While typing notes, suddenly Notepad++ wasn't responding to keystrokes correctly. Hitting delete did nothing, or would delete an entire line, or add keystrokes I didn't type. I could place my cursor anywhere even if I didn't have spaces there. I can't use the delete or space keys to add or remove spaces. Numbers aren't working. I can't highlight and type over, or move the cursor using "HOME / END" keys...or even the cursor keys in fact.

In searching, it sounds partially like "virtual spaces" that would allow someone to place a cursor anywhere, though doesn't seem like that's an option and I never knowingly enabled it. I want the opposite - only allow to type if there are spaces (like a "dumb" editor). I've used Notepad++ for over a decade, never ran into this...assuming I hit some obscure key stroke setting but can't find it.

Encoding is set to UTF-8. Tried toggling INS/OVR. Typing is normal in every other window/app. Language is set to "None (Normal Text)"

Open to any suggestions, thanks!

Comment: Is it happening for every file? Is Read-only enabled (Edit->Set Read-Only)?

Comment: Read-Only was not enabled. And yeah, was happening in every open file in each window (of Notepad++ - had about 7 windows open with multiple files in each one)